# How can i assign a App Setting to Private Constant

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I am storing some program values in my Web.config file and would like to use them in my Code.
When i try to set the value like this.

```
Private Const Security As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("jwtKey")
```

i get the error Constant expression is required. Is there a way to make this work or do i have to assign the value to each function in my controller which needs access to this constant.

Comment: You can’t. Consts must be compile-time constants, and clearly yours could be different on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use the [ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/readonly) attribute:

```
Private ReadOnly Security As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("jwtKey")
```

From the MSDN article:

> Specifies that a variable or property can be read but not written.

Just what you are describing, assign a value to a variable but do not allow it to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This what a constructor is for

```vb
Class MyController

    Private Const Security As String 

    Public Sub New

      Security = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("jwtKey")

    End Sub
```

If you're using DI, you could pass all the relevant options in as a single object